# updating a single column either 1 or 2 in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form and I want to update the database. If I want to update only line 1 in input field or line 2 input field then how is this possible using update query? Note: I want the previous data leave as it was store in database.

This is from code.

```
    <?php  include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php

if(isset($_POST) && count($_POST)>0) {

    $description1 = $_POST['line1_desc'];
    $description2 = $_POST['line2_desc'];

    $sSQL =mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_images SET $description1,$description2 Where id=".intval($_GET['id']));
    if($sSQL){
        echo 'done';
    }
    else {
        mysql_error();
    }

    //header("location: show_property_pic.php");
}

?>

<div>

    <form name="frmProudct" id="frmProduct" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table align='center'>
            <tr>
                <td>Line1:</td>
                <td> <textarea cols="100" name="line1_desc"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <td>Line2:</td>
                <td> <textarea cols="100" name="line2_desc"></textarea></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="submit" id="btnSub" value="Save"  /> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>

<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? In which case, the `HTML` you provided is needed to solve a `PHP` and `MySQL` Problem?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I apologize for this I have now edited my code please check it and help me. Thanks

Comment: Your SQL statement doesn't make sense. Concentrate on writing a valid UPDATE statement in SQL before you try to incorporate it into PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the second textarea optional, you could just create a initial string (which is the first textarea), then just append the second one if its not empty. Consider this example: [**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TcYgsz)

```
if(isset($_POST['line1_desc']) && (trim($_POST['line1_desc']) != '')) {
    $input[] = "`line1_desc` = '" . $_POST['line1_desc'] ."'";
}
if(isset($_POST['line2_desc']) && (trim($_POST['line2_desc']) != '')) {
    $input[] = "`line2_desc` = '" . $_POST['line2_desc'] ."'";
}

$values = implode(', ', $input);

$statement = "UPDATE `tbl_images` SET $values WHERE `id` = your_id";
echo $statement;

// if both textareas have input:
// UPDATE `tbl_images` SET `line1_desc` = 'comment 1', `line2_desc` = 'comment 2' WHERE `id` = your_id
// if only line1_desc1 textarea is only provided:
// UPDATE `tbl_images` SET `line1_desc` = '1' WHERE `id` = your_id
// if only line1_desc2 textarea is only provided:
// UPDATE `tbl_images` SET `line2_desc` = '2' WHERE `id` = your_id
```

> Note: If possible, migrate/use the newer version of mysql extension which is **`MYSQLI`** or use **`PDO`**

Comment: Oh sorry I understand it. As you said that use mysqli_ so I have tried many times but it gives Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given.

Comment: @qaser if your using mysqli_query now, you need to provide the connection, then the query itself. sample: `$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');` then feed it on `$query = mysqli_query($con, 'update blah blah query');`

Comment: I have used your fiddle example in my page it is working when echo the statement variable but I use this '$statement =mysql_query( "UPDATE `tbl_images` SET $values WHERE `id` = 1");' then this only change line1_desc and when input in both fields it works fine but when I input data in line 2 then it does not work or update the database. Please help me why this is happening.

Comment: as you mentioned to use the newer version of mysql extension then I will use it later because for this I will change lot of pages.

Comment: @qaser if you want them to be more dynamic you could put them inside the array then `implode()`. i updated the whole answer and the check the new fiddle. regarding mysqli, if its too late to migrate now (e.g. the project is in the later stages now) then, maybe the next one, thats why i said if possible

Comment: ok I understand and it is working now really appreciate your answer. But there are still errors when use implode(). Like "Notice: Undefined variable: input" and "Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed".

Comment: @qaser it errors if `$input` is not initialized above the conditions. just put `$input = array()` above the if. or better if you dont process the form if both textareas are empty. seems logical anyway

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, your SQL Statement is Wrong.

It should be:

```
'UPDATE <tablename> SET <fieldname> = "<Content>", <fieldname> = "<Content>" WHERE <Condition>'
```

In your case

```
'UPDATE tbl_images SET description1 = "' . $description1 . '", description2 = "' . $description2 . '" Where id='.intval($_GET['id'])
```

But please inform about `SQL Injection` and `Prepared Statements`. And Stop using `mysql_` functions right now! Better to use `mysqli_` for fast migration even `PDO`, wich is 1.000 times better.

Comment: Oh sorry I understand it. As you said that use mysqli_ so I have tried many times but it gives Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given.

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php You must change all to `mysqli_` not only `mysqli_query`. Also take a look at `PDO`: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers